# Optimizing a java multithreaded server that uses an inputstreamreader

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, parsing

I'm currently working on a project where i have to host a server wich fetches an inputstream, parses the data and sends it to the database. Every client that connects to my server sends an inputstream wich never stops once it is connected. Every client is assigned a socket and its own parser thread object so the server can deal with the datastream coming from the client. The parser object just deals with the incoming data and sends it to the database.

Server / parser generator:

```
public void generateParsers() {
    while (keepRunning) {
        try {
            Socket socket = s.accept();
            // new connection
            t = new Thread(new Parser(socket));
            t.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            appLog.severe(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Parser thread:

```
   @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!socket.isClosed() && socket.isConnected()) {
            try {
                BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                String line = bufReader.readLine();
                String data = "";
                if (line == null) {
                    socket.close();
                } else if (Objects.equals(line, "<DATA")) {
                    while (!Objects.equals(line, "</DATA>")) {
                        data += line;
                        line = bufReader.readLine();
                    }
                    /*
                    Send the string that was build            
                    from the client's datastream to the database
                    using the parse() function.         
                    */
                    parse(data);
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("ERROR : " + e);
            }
        }
    }
```

My setup is functional but the problem is that it delivers too much stress on my server when too much clients are connected and thus too many threads are parsing data concurrently. The parsing of the incoming data and the sending of the data to the database is hardly effecting the performance at all. The bottleneck is mostly the concurrent reading of the client's datastreams from the connected clients.

Is there any way that i can optimize my current setup ? I was thinking of capping the amount of connections and once a full datafile is recieved, parse it and move to the next client in the connection que or something similar.

Comment: `data += line;` you can refactor this String concatenation using `StringBuilder`. Also you can profile your code to find if there are any specific bottlenecks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The bottleneck is mostly the concurrent reading

No. The bottleneck is string concatenation. Use a `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder`.

And probably improper behaviour when a client disconnects. It's hard to believe this works at all. It shouldn't:

- You should use the same `BufferedReader` for the life of the socket, otherwise you can lose data.
- `Socket.isClosed()` and `Socket.isConnected()` don't do what you think they do: the correct loop termination condition is `readLine()` returning null, or throwing an `IOException`:

  ```
  while ((line = bufReader.readLine()) != null)
  ```

Capping the number of concurrent connections can't possibly achieve anything if the clients never disconnect. All you'll accomplish is never listening to clients beyond the first *N* to connect, which can't possibly be what you want. 'Move to the next client' will never happen.

Answer (score 2):

If your problem is indeed that whatever you are doing while client is connected is expensive, you will have to use client queue. The most simple way to do this will be to use `ExecutorService` with N numer of max threads.

For example

```
private ExecutorService pool=Executors.newFixedThreapPool(N);
```

...
and then

```
Socket socket = s.accept();
pool.submit(new Parser(socket)));
```

This will limit concurent client handling to N at the time, and queue any additional clients that exceeds N.

Also depends on what you are doing with the data, you could always split the process to phases for example

1. Read raw data from client and enqueue for processing - close socket etc. so you can save resources
2. Process the data in separate thread (possibly thread pool) and enqueue the result
3. Do something with the result (check for validity, persist into DB etc) in another pool.

This is especially helpfull if you got some blocking operations like network I/O, or expensive one etc.

Looks like in your case, client does not have to wait for whole backend proess to complete. He only needs to deliver the data, so splitting data reading and parsing/persisting into separate phases (subtasks) sounds like reasonable approach.